# NodeJS MongoDB Count entries with same value in field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following collection

```
_id: someid
name: Name 1
status: 0
ref: 152

_id: someid
name: Name 1
status: 0
ref: 152

_id: someid
name: Name 1
status: 3
ref: 152

_id: someid
name: Name 1
status: 0
ref: 273

_id: someid
name: Name 1
status: 3
ref: 679
```

I'd like to get a result that tells me how many times "ref" appears with the same value where the entry has the status anything except 3. So for example the result I'm looking for is basically

```
{"152": 2, "273": 1, "679": 0}
```

Since "ref: 152" appears 2 times while the status is not 3 and "ref: 273" appears 1 times while the status is not 3. I'm using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB. I've tried to aggregate which to an extent does work however since 679 has 0 the aggregation result omits "679: 0" and that causes the React template to throw an error declaring it undefined. Using aggregation also formats it differently so occasionally the wrong amount is displayed on different rows. I feel if I can access the count by using the reference number as the key it'd be accurate but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

EDIT: I have solved my issue like this:

```
const count = {}

docs.map((doc) => {
    count[doc.ref] = 0
})

docs.map((doc) => {
    doc.status < 3 && count[doc.ref]++
})
```

Which returns exactly what I specified I needed above however I was wondering if there was an even cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Array.reduce()** function as well.

```
const countRef = docs.reduce((count, doc) => {
  count[doc.ref] = (doc.status !== 3) ? (count[doc.ref] || 0) + 1 : (count[doc.ref] || 0);
  return count;
}, {});

// countRef - {"152": 2, "273": 1, "679": 0}
```